# jdk 8 .exe disappears when installing

Tags: java

I have installed jdk 8 and then I removed it and all the other version installed on my computer 
I want to reinstall jdk 8u171 but when I run jdk.exe it disappears 
Please help me

Comment: Define `it disappears` please.

Comment: weird though, i've [several jdks](https://imgur.com/a/yvXEFa1) installed on mine (WIndows 10) and they are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on windows 10. Seems to be a problem with their installers. Work around was to use the Netbeans + JDK bundled installer. Uninstall Netbeans later. this installer did not seem to have this problem.

Comment: Disappear means the installer doesn't launch

Comment: I don't have NetBeans installed on my computer

Comment: I am suggesting you to use the netbeans + jdk installer. This installer works fine and circumvents the above problem. All you need to do then is remove netbeans if you dont need. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html